# Which data encryption technology should I use?

Tags: encryption, md5, sha

I'm some newbie of data encryption. I goggling data encryption and mostly found md5 and SHA algorithms.Which technology do you consider to be the best for data storage/security and why?

Comment: Neither MD5 nor SHA encrypt data. Google some more.

Comment: Those are not encryption algorithms. Those are hashing algorithms. IIRC AES was a very good current encryption algorithm.

Comment: So you need to hash passwords or encrypt data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MD5 and SHA are hash functions, they create fingerprint - fixed-length representation - from the bunch of data. For example, they are extensively used as a way to check consistency of your iso image downloads for many open-source products, but this means you can use them to create fingerprints from any selection of bytes. So they do not encrypt.

If you want to encrypt, you should check for encryption algorithms. The most feasible now I believe is AES (Advanced encryption Standard) if you look for symmetric encryption algorithms (eg. where key for encryption and decryption is the same or easily computed one from another) or RSA if you look for asymmetric (where you have 2 keys - public and private, and compute private key from public is hard task).

If you are about to create digital signatures, you may want to check things like DSA (digital signature algorithm) and ECDSA (DSA over elliptic curves.). Note that asymmetric algorithms work over numbers with extended precision - like 512, 1024, 2048 bits and so on. You need special libraries that can handle such numbers. If you use C++ I can recommend you trying Crypto++. Find something similar for other languages.

I hope this was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is password and you want to store it some where then Use `MD5` or `SHA` Hash.
There are two advantages of these.

1. A hash can not be decrypted to recover old value so your password will never ever will be cracked even if you provide MD5/SHA hash of password to some one :)
2. A hash of particular string will be always same so you can compare passwords based on Hash.

AES :

1. Symmetric algorithm so faster
2. Use with PKCS5Padding and CBC mode
3. Always store IV
4. Symmetric so you need same key while you are decrypting encrypted text so you can not at all share keys.

RSA

1. PKI Infrastructure to exchange Keys
2. Slow

There are other algorithms also Like DES(Not So Secure), 3DES(Often called Tripple DES- Not enough secure compared to DES)